# Django installation on Mac

Tags: django

I'm trying to install Django on Mac,  Python version 3.7  already installed , here is the comment I have put in terminal-

`Django-admin startproject hello`

- command not found

Comment: `pip install django` is done?

Comment: hit **pip freeze** and see weather django is install

Answer (score 0):

pip install virtualenv ,
virtualenv some name inside the less than and greater than sign ,
and then cd into the  directory and run:
,
source bin/activate,
pip install Django

hope this will help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps to install and use django

1. Install django. `$ python -m pip install --upgrade django`
2. Now, check the installation `$ python -m pip freeze | grep django`
3. Create django project `$ django-admin startproject mysite`

**What i see wrong in your question ?** You are using *Django-admin*